# How to translate the OlCategoryColor?

Tags: c#

I'm using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;` that allows me to use the `OlCategoryColor`. In particular I've this:

```
Dictionary<OlCategoryColor, KeyValuePair<string, string>> CategoryColor;
CategoryColor = new Dictionary<OlCategoryColor, KeyValuePair<string, string>>
 {
    {OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorRed, new KeyValuePair<string, string>("#E7A1A2", "7")}
 };
```

To get the name of the color, I simply do this:

```
foreach (var outlookColor in CategoryColor)
{
   outlookColor.Key.ToString().Remove(0, "olCategoryColor".Length);
}
```

It returns `Red`, but is it possible to take the Italian language or other languages?

Comment: `Enum.ToString` returns name of enumeration as in the source code, if you want to translate that into Italian you must do it yourself - a simple dictionary mapping english -> italian names with a bit of Google Translating should do

Comment: @csharpfolk Please, show me an example code if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is *simple* solution, you may want to tweak it a little depending on wherever do you want to support many languages or just Italian:

```
public enum Language {
    English,
    Italian
}

public static class LocalizationHelper {

    private static IDictionary<string, string> eng2ItalianColor = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "Red", "Rosso" },
        { "Black", "Nero" },
        { "Blue", "Azzurro" },
        // other ...
    };

    public static string GetColorName(OlCategoryColor color, Language language) {
        var englishColorName = 
            color.ToString().Remove(0, "olCategoryColor".Length);

        if (language == Language.English) {
            return englishColorName;
        }
        else if (language == Language.Italian) {
            if (eng2ItalianColor.ContainsKey(englishColorName))
                return eng2ItalianColor[englishColorName];
            else
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    "missing translation from english to italian for color: " + englishColorName);
        }
        else {
            throw new ArgumentException("unsupported language: " + language);
        }
    }
}

// Then use:
var colorName = 
    LocalizationHelper.GetColorName(outlookColor.Key, Language.Italian);
```

If you google a little maybe you will find a ready translation table for colors, I used simple `dict` linux utility that allows to translate words from command line.

Depending on application you are writing, there may be a case that you will also need to translate other strings/messages, in that case you should check some tutorials on Globalization solutions for .NET - generally you would create several resource files - one per language and then use ResourceManager or other class to load strings based on `Thread.CurrentCulture`. In that case as resource name you may use e.g. `color_red` and for each language provide appropriate translation. Quick tutorial here: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/What-is-Globalization-and-Localization-and-their-differences-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Very interesting solution thanks :) But I don't understand a thing: you've declared a `color` variable inside `GetColorName` but you never use it, why?